# Add method to typed arrays in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, generics, typescript

How can I add a method to a typed array like `Array<MyClass>`?

Consider a case where you have a typed array where it might make sense to offer a property/method to calculate a value by accessing all items of the array.

```typescript
class Foo {
    date: Date
}

class FooArray extends Array<Foo> {

    dateInterval() {
        // Some algorithm that iterates over all dates to find
        // min/max
        return this.reduce(..)
    }
}
```

But something tells me that I'm going the wrong way. For example, `FooArray.splice()` returns the type `Foo[]`, not `FooArray`, which makes total sense to me.

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll provide 2 options for you

**Casting**

Just explicitly add the splice method to *override* the inherited method to return your preferred type, with casts

```
splice() {
  let arr = super.splice();
  return new FooArray(arr); // or some other way of casting
}
```

---

Alternatively, wrapping

**Wrapping**

```
class FooArray {

    constructor(private arr: Foo[]) { /* maybe copy the array...? */ }    

    splice(start: number, end?: number) {
        return new FooArray(this.arr.splice(start, end));
    }
}
```

This way you must be explicit about what you expose, rather than mixing the inherited base class' methods that will return normal arrays. Take your pick.

Comment: thanks, I was hoping for some magic, but being explicit about what is exposed is probably just the way to go.